# Displaying dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to select all the rows where Voice == Lower and then create a new dataframe to store all the corresponding teams and amounts.

This is the code I have so far:

```
df = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx")
df = df['Team', 'Voice', 'Amount']
df = df.groupby(['Team', 'Voice'])['Amount'].sum()
lower = df.loc[['Voice' == 'Lower']]
```

But when I do print(lower), it prints:

```
Series([], Name: Amount, dtype: float64)
```

rather than the dataframe itself. How do I display the dataframe itself?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Could you please update your post with sample input / output data ? This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) should help you get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
df = df.reset_index(inplace=True)    
lower = df[df['Voice'] == 'Lower']
print(lower)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately I just tried it and it's still printing the same thing

Comment: You have a key error because 'Voice' has became an index of df after the groupby. Do `df.reset_index(inplace=True)` before `lower = df[df['Voice'] == 'Lower'] `

Comment: @Renaud Brilliant, thank you! At first I got an error but I changed it to df = df.reset_index and it worked!

Comment: What about using double square bracket `df = df.groupby(['Team', 'Voice'])[['Amount']].agg('sum').reset_index()`